# Formik useField hook doesn't pass name or label props?

Tags: reactjs, formik

My goal really isn't too complex, I need custom behaviour for the form fields (input, select and date) `onBlur()`.

Am starting off with the input because the select and datepicker components have additional requirements and will likely be packages.

According to the docs I should be able to create a custom component and use it with `<Field as />` or `<Field component />` neither of which work the way I expect (or hope).

Seems like I'm missing something extremely basic, but I map over the data which has a structure like this:

```
interface CaseSummaryFiltersInterface {
  order: number;
  name: string;
  testid: string;
  label: string;
  // ...superfluous stuff...
}

// Part of Form component
{filters?.map((filter, filterIndex) => {
  return <Field name={filter.name} component={CustomInput} />;
})}

// CustomInput.tsx
type CustomInputProps = {
  name: string;
  label: string;
  type?: 'InputType';
  className?: string;
} & Omit<DetailedHTMLProps<InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>, HTMLInputElement>, 'size'>;

export const CustomInput: FC<CustomInputProps> = props => {
  const [field] = useField({
    name: props.name,
  });
  console.log(props.name); // undefined
  console.log(field); // {name: undefined, values: {...thingsIneed} }

  const handleUpdate = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    // things I need to do
  };

  return (
    <div data-testid="form-control">
      <input
        type="text"
        {...field}
        className={FormStyles.formInput}
        onBlur={handleUpdate}
        name={props.name}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

If I just use `<Field />` on it's own then I have access to everything I need but none of the functionality that is required. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing the component prop and the useField hook.

If you want to use the component prop, your `CustomInput` component will receive the props field and form. To access the field name you have to use `props.field.name` not `props.name`

If you want to use the useField hook, you dont need to use `<Field />` at all.
Just use `<CustomInput name="name" />`

More info at https://formik.org/docs/api/field#component and https://formik.org/docs/api/useField

Comment: So I've put together a quick [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-shirley-q65b76?file=/src/App.tsx) in the logged field object as you can see when I get the correct name then value is empty which is the stuff I need. If I get the value object then the name will be empty.

Comment: @Rue because you are only passing name to useField. You should be doing `ùseField(props)`